# Orientdb client using 100% cpu after connection has been established

Tags: orientdb

When I use the following code in a servlet running in tomcat7 (also tested in tomcat6) on Ubuntu 10.10 Server (openjdk 1.6.0_20 64bit), the java process uses 100% cpu and above after the connection has been established once.

```
ODatabaseObjectTx db = ODatabaseObjectPool.global().acquire("remote:localhost/test", "test", "test");
db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(BlogPost.class);
List<BlogPost> posts = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<BlogPost>("select * from BlogPost order by date desc"));
db.close();
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

EDIT:
The issue also happens right after acquire. There is a Thread "ClientService" being spawned that causes the high load. 
I took several thread dumps and it always shows the same for this thread:

```
"ClientService" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4d88344800 nid=0x558e runnable [0x00007f4d872da000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:127)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1239)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:431)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynch.endResponse(OChannelBinaryAsyn
ch.java:73)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteServiceThread.execute(OStorageRemoteServiceThread
.java:59)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:48)
```

When I suspend the thread in the debugger, the high load stops until I press continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens after the acquire() or the query?

Comment: I just removed the query completely and it still happens => It happens after acquire().

Comment: Can you try with latest SVN trunk? There is bug on that class fixed for another issue.

Comment: I checked out the latest cilent from the trunk and the issue seems to be resolved. Do you know when this version will be available in a maven repository?

Comment: Great! It's planned for 15th June but it could be released earlier if some high-priority bugs are found/fixed